# Deleting files from local app Documents folder

Tags: ios, tableview

So far I have managed to delete rows from my table view but it won't update in the given Documents folder. How would I achieve this? Below is the code I'm using.

I tried to implement the code from here [How to delete files from a folder which is placed in documents folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473858/how-to-delete-files-from-a-folder-which-is-placed-in-documents-folder/16952057#16952057).

My goal is to have the ability to delete any file, not just a desired file.

Thanks in advance.

```
#import "Documents.h"

@interface DocumentsViewController ()

@end

@implementation DocumentsViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;


    NSString *temp = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    self.directoryPath = [temp stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

    [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];



}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [directoryContents count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        // Configure the cell.
        cell.textLabel.text = [directoryContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
}


-(NSString*)directoryPath{
    return directoryPath;
}

-(void)setDirectoryPath:(NSString*)a{
    [a retain];
    [directoryPath release];
    directoryPath = a;
    [self loadDirectoryContents];
    [table reloadData];
}

-(void)loadDirectoryContents{
    [directoryContents release];
    directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: directoryPath];
    [directoryContents retain];
}

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { //implement the delegate method

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Update data source array here, something like [array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [directoryContents removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView reloadData];


        NSString *extension = @"png";
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSArray *contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:NULL];
        NSEnumerator *e = [contents objectEnumerator];
        NSString *filename;
        while ((filename = [e nextObject])) {

            if ([[filename pathExtension] isEqualToString:extension]) {

                [fileManager removeItemAtPath:[documentsDirectory     stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] error:NULL];
            }
        }

    }
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];    
    [directoryContents release];
    directoryContents = nil;
    self.directoryPath = nil;
    [table release];
    table = nil;

}

@end
```

WORKING CODE FOR ME:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){

        NSString *fileName = [directoryContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString *path;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"downloads"];
        path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        NSError *error;

    //Remove cell
        [directoryContents removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        [tableView reloadData];

        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])     //Does file exist?
        {
            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:&error])   //Delete it
            {
                NSLog(@"Delete file error: %@", error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: The issue is that when swiping to delete in my table view, it will delete that row, but not the actual file in the folder. So refreshing my table view shows the file again.

Comment: The code you posted is trying to delete the entire `directoryPath` folder under the `Documents` folder. You should append the actual filename and not just an empty string. It also helps to check the return value of `removeItemAtPath`. It it returns `NO` then log the `error` value so you can see the actual problem.

Comment: Thats the thing, I don't want that to be tied into a specific file. The row im removing in the table responds to the Documents folder. But the folder does not update with the deletion.

Comment: Try changing jpg to png in the code snippet I created and see if you can remove the png files with that.

Comment: Just updated my answer with deleting file from specific folder.

Comment: The specific code doesn't work. Your previous code with the extension type did, but the file path was off. Tried changing some things around, but no luck :(

Comment: @ChrisOSX Did you check the result of `removeItemAtPath:error:`? Does it return `NO`? What is the error?

Comment: I'm using the first part he posted as that actually deleted the file, BUT the path is wrong. It's linking to the standard Documents folder, it needs to be my apps local Document folder.

Answer (score 6):

`NSFileManager` is very useful in removing files:

```
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath: pathToFile error: &error];
```

Also take a look at this article it has some useful codes. Although a bit old but the codes works just fine.

> http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/3576-how-do-i-delete-a-file-in-my-documents-directory.html

Here is some more code example

```
// Get the Documents directory path 
NSString *temPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",@"Documents/Media_",  Key_mediaID];
//This temPath look line ../../../Documents/Media_1

  NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSHomeDirectory()  stringByAppendingPathComponent:temPath]; 

// Delete the file using NSFileManager
 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:[documentsDirectoryPath   stringByAppendingPathComponent:Your File Name] error:nil];
```

Here is another link with some more helpful code

> http://ios.biomsoft.com/2012/01/17/delete-all-files-in-documents-directory/

Hope this helps you out.

**Edit:**

To remove a files with specific extension say for example jpg you can try the following

```
    NSString *extension = @"jpg";
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:NULL];  
    NSEnumerator *e = [contents objectEnumerator];
    NSString *filename;
    while ((filename = [e nextObject])) {

    if ([[filename pathExtension] isEqualToString:extension]) {

    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:[documentsDirectory     stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] error:NULL];
   }
   }
```

In addition to the above if you know the path to the file you want to delete the following is a useful code:

```
// Get the Documents directory path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// Delete the file using NSFileManager
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:[documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:yourFile.txt] error:nil];
```

**Edit 2:**

To delete the document in a specific folder:

```
NSError *error;
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documents= [documentsDirectory  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourFolder"];
NSString *filePath = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file2.txt"];
[fileMgr removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error]
```

Comment: To me this line: stringByAppendingPathComponent:Your File Name, is stating I want to delete a specific named file. I'm trying to avoid this.

Comment: Then try the link for deleting all the files in directory at the very bottom of my answer.

Comment: Still won't update the folder. Original post updated with my whole .m file for better reference.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you are trying to delete a file with extention png, why don't you try the code snippet I provided for jpg and just change it to png? It might do the trick.

Comment: That's what I did. Same code except for the different extension type.

Comment: Ok update. Your code directs to the documents directory, where I need it to point to my apps Document folder. I copied a png there, with the same name, and it deleted. Just the path is off.

Comment: Any more info I can use? My documents path is in /Applications/MyApp/Documents.

Comment: The third code snippet that removes the file related to the extension jpg should work with png as well. That is how I did it for a project that I had that requirement. Beyound that I am out of option brother. I have given you all the options I know. The only other thing is leave the question open to see if someone else has a better idea.

Comment: Forgot I created this thread when I created new one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113348/removing-files-from-table-view-and-folder. Only this one specifies a folder in the documents directory. Any help would, as always be appreciated.

Comment: Found ad added my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113348/removing-files-from-table-view-and-folder